# Which formula to use for drag simulation each frame?

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

My rigidbody has a velocity and I defined a variable `float drag = 0.995f` so that:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    rb.velocity *= drag;
}
```

It's working fine but I guess I have to use `Time.deltaTime` to make the drag time-consistent, so my question is how to write a time-consistent drag formula? Should I just set `drag` as a really big value and write `rb.velocity *= drag * Time.deltaTime` and tune `drag` until I'm satisfied?

I just thought of using `rb.velocity *= (1 - drag * Time.deltaTime)` and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: The drag coefficient is usually defined by `dv/dt = - drag * v`, so the correct factor to multiply by is `exp(- drag * ΔT)` — of which the expression `1 - drag * Time.deltaTime` is a first-order expansion. This prevents "overshoot" in cases where `drag * Time.deltaTime > 1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Both will work**.

Since you're using `FixedUpdate` you'll also want to use [fixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) instead of `deltaTime`.

```
rb.velocity *= drag * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
rb.velocity *= (1 - drag * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Which formula you use is really up to personal preference. Be aware the first one will decrease the actual drag as the drag value increases.

Comment: From [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html): `When this is called from inside MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate, it returns Time.fixedDeltaTime.` -> it makes no difference